# Make .ipa for iPhone, not iPad using PhoneGap Build

Tags: ios, cordova, ipad, app-store, phonegap-build

I'm trying to submit an iPhone-only app to the store. I'm building using PhoneGap Build.

I found this SO question (from 2013): [Phonegap targeting only iPhone (not iPad)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13521406/phonegap-targeting-only-iphone-not-ipad) saying to use `<preference name="target-device" value="handset" />` but it's not working. The .ipa file continues to declare support for iPad

It appears to be a known issue: https://github.com/phonegap/build/issues/504

I'm wondering if anyone else has had to deal with this recently? And if there are any workarounds. Any tricks?

I've started the submission process anyway, but have had the app rejected a couple of times so far for iPad related style/sizing issues. I'm going to try and pick through the issues as a back up plan, but I don't need to support iPad so I'd like to just submit a iPhone only version

Note: I can't build without PhoneGap build at the moment. I need to upgrade my Mac OS to get the newer xcode to compile using Cordova on my machine. I'm in Vietnam right now, with terrible internet, and can't do it at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed in GitHub issue 504 https://github.com/phonegap/build/issues/504

I've tested this and it's good.